# A question shows formatted in preview but unformatted on the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown

The code in this question:

[Retrieve a value inside a stored procedure and use it inside that stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676029/retrieve-a-value-inside-a-stored-procedure-and-use-it-inside-that-stored-procedur)

is shown as unformatted to me in `FF 3.6.3`

However, when I press edit, the code seems to be 4-spaces indented and shows formatted in the preview.

Comment: Strange. You're correct. The relevant revision is no. 3, which is unformatted in the [revision list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2676029/revisions), but formatted in the [WMD preview](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2676029/edit/9d0f5143-c7e4-46cf-8dc2-e93799c5c7d6); and it's correctly [4-space indented](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9d0f5143-c7e4-46cf-8dc2-e93799c5c7d6/view-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the code and hit the "101010" button in the edit. See if it changes.

Comment: It did change. However, revision 3 of the post: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2676029/revisions used the same formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9d0f5143-c7e4-46cf-8dc2-e93799c5c7d6/view-source but did not show right.

Comment: @quass I suspect non-printable characters.

Comment: @jeff: non-printable characters as opposed to spaces? :)

Comment: @quass I mean like tabs or unicode spaces. At any rate, [no-repro]

Comment: Marking this as accepted since it fixed this very post, however, one can still observe the bug in the revision list.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is code
```

Code blocks don't always show up correctly at the start of a post. I think this has been reported before, but I can't find it.

Comment: not true for months, that was an extremely old bug pre-MarkdownSharp

Comment: @Jeff: I'm pretty sure I've seen this within the last month, though, but I didn't make a note of the post because it was a known bug.

Answer (score 0):

Add some empty lines before the code block to work around it.

Comment: not necessary..

Comment: @Jeff: It used to be necessary, was this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDUREgetData(IN templateName VARCHAR(45),IN templateVersion VARCHAR(45),IN userId VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
```

notice code block at start of post.